# How can I detect "stylized" text?

Tags: javascript, regex

I was wondering if there was a way to detect if a text is "stylized", like these:

> ʇxǝʇ uʍop-ǝp!sdn
>
> ⓣⓔⓧⓣ ⓢⓣⓨⓛⓔ
>
> ＴＲＡＮＳＭＩＴＴＩＮＧ
>
> I͇̜̦̦͇̬ͥ͆̀͠'̵̖̠͉̞͓̯̋̑̾̎̽̐ͫͣm̡̠͚̌̽̊̕͢ ̲̰̠̦̝̥̏͋̄̒ͯ̎̄̅̂͝b̷̛̻̎ͬ̚e̵͍̪̯̺̘̣̩̪̭ͨ̇̈̄̌̃̋̉͘h̶̖̮̦ͯͫ̂ͥ̍ͯ̌́͆͞i̸͙͙̖̹̳̝̭̱͗ͤ̌͢n̰͇̟̪̹̭͎͔͐̃ͧ͋ͥ̉d̵̬̰͌̆ͪ͆̔ͯͩ̈́͜ ͚͎͎̽͌̆̒ͬ̀̕y̵͇̰ͧ͊̈́͛͊̓o̤̳̍͌̉ͪ͒u̹͉̝̲̥ͮ̄͟͡

can regex be used to detect those?

(also, sorry if there's a word for those text, I don't know how they're called and I can't find it anywhere)

Comment: I don't know, but if you need to block invalid characters it's usually better to define a range of allowed ones.

Comment: You might need to define 'stylized' a bit more, you could try with unicode, if you mean : not alphanumeric

Comment: There are various patterns for stylized texts. Either you will define all of them, too, or just make sure no diacritics can be used in your input.

Comment: @Praveen: The target question is not an appropriate duplicate for this problem. The other question deals with astral code points in JavaScript. This question deals with various equivalent visual representation of English alphabet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are actually special characters, not stylized text, and you can filter them with a regex like this:

```
var myText = "abc ⓣⓔⓧⓣ ʇxǝʇ uʍop-ǝp!sdn";
var findSpecial = myText.replace(/[\w\s]/g, ""); // \w is for word chars (letters and numbers) and \s for space; g is for general search (all ocurrences) to replace all regular chars and leave the specials
if (findSpecial != "") { 
    alert("Text has special char(s): " + findSpecial);
} else {
    alert("Text has no special chars.");
}
```

In this example, the alert will be: 
*Text has special char(s): ⓣⓔⓧⓣʇǝʇʍ-ǝ!*